# How to put default text in input fields while keeping JS form validation functionality

Tags: javascript, forms

Some jQuery plugin checks whether my form fields (text input and select) have been filled out before I can submit the form. Now I want to add default values in the fields such as "please enter your name". But if I do that, the JS plugin will validate these fields whereas in fact the user didn't enter anything in them.

I want JS NOT to validate fields containing a default value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Placeholder` in your fields

EX:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="please enter your name">
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that I want to apply default values both to input fields and select fields. I think placeholder cannot be used for a select. What can I do about it then?

Comment: Default value??"please enter your name" cannot be a default value!! or is it?and for makinga default value selected in select box do this : <option selected="selected">default value</option

Comment: Sorry I didn't use the right word. Instead of default value, I meant really the same thing as a placeholder, but in a select element rather than in an input text element. If I do <option selected="selected">Please select an option</option> and if the user doesn't select anything then submits, the JS plugin will validate the select because it will see a value selected. I want that, in the eyes of the plugin, no value was selected in this case.